# Checkbox not refreshing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am facing an issue as below.

I have two drop-down, first one is single drop down select, second one is multi select drop-down checkbox. Second one shows the result based on the first drop-down value.

While select the first drop-down, I get the values for second drop-down to show(Values Show in Inspect element) but not in drop down.

Please find the below code for further reference.

**abc.html**

```
<select  name="list_usergroup[]" multiple id="list_usergroup" >
<option value=""> Select User Group </option>                   
</select>
```

**mg.js**

```
org_uuid = $('#list_organization').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: appGetSecureURL("/api/web/getorgug/" + org_uuid),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        beforeSend : function(){
            loaderOn();
        },
        success: function(data) {

            // Display Usergroups
            if (0 == data.ug_total) {
                $("#list_usergroup").html('<option value="">No Usergroup.</option>');
            }
            else {
                $("#list_usergroup").html("");
                $("#list_usergroup").html('<option value="">Select Usergroup</option>');
                for (rowData in data.usergroups) 
                {
                    var optionData = '<option data = "'+ data.usergroups[rowData] +'" value="'+ rowData+'">' + data.usergroups[rowData]+'</option>';
                    $('#list_usergroup').val("");
                    $('#list_usergroup').multiselect('refresh');
                    $('#list_usergroup').multiselect('reset');
                    $("#list_usergroup").append(optionData);
                }

                //$('#list_usergroup').multiselect('reset');
                $("#list_usergroup").multiselect({
                            columns: 1,
                            placeholder: 'Select Usergroups',
                            search: true,
                            selectAll: true,
                            onLoad: function() {

                            }
                    });
                $("#list_usergroup").val(Value);
            }
            loaderOff();            
        },
        error: function(data, b, c) {
            appLog.debug("Display Usergroup error Status  " + data.status + ": " + data.statusText)
        }
    })
```

I am using https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect plugin

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to call this `$('#list_usergroup').multiselect('refresh');
                    $('#list_usergroup').multiselect('reset');` after `$("#list_usergroup").val(Value);` line

Comment: It's not working. any other suggestions?

Comment: Please include in the question which multiselect plugin you are using. Also try to strip away code that has nothing to do with your problem, such as the AJAX call (read how to make a [mcve]). This will make it easier to help you.

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: I don't see a question in your post. Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: @tree except you all understood my question. Tell me what clarification you want?

Answer (score 0):

To Enable Multiselect with refresh data. you have to re-initialise Multiselect.

```
$('#list_usergroup').multiselect('destroy');  // tell widget to clear itself
$('#list_usergroup').multiselect(); // re-initialize the widget
```